# How can I search for good spots to ride on inline skates / rollerblades?

Tags: inline-skating

#### Question

How can I search for locations with a smooth surface where I can ride my inline skates? What sources or methods can I use?

#### Context

I recently picked up inline skating and noticed that the road surface makes a huge difference in the pleasure I get from skating.
I have a park nearby that has wide, asphalt roads with no car traffic, which is perfect.
To keep things diverse I would like to look for other spots with similar characteristics, i.e.:

- smooth surface, e.g. maintained asphalt or large concrete slabs
- little motorized traffic
- wide paths

#### What I've tried

- I checked Google Maps satellite view to see if I could identify smooth roads. That appears to be hit and miss, as some path look smooth but actually aren't and some paths (e.g. the one I ride on in the park) are obscured by folliage.
- I tried looking for rooftop parking garages. Unfortunately the ones in my neighbourhood don't have a smooth surface.
- I tried using [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) queries to search for smooth ways in my neighbourhood. However, I have not yet found a helpful combination of query conditions.

Comment: The slightly unhelpful answer I'd give here is the same way I find good places to go for a run: talk to local runners (or skaters in your case).

Comment: Yes, that would of course be an option, although I prefer to keep to myself. Perhaps as a last resort :)